# Sincronização Método Java Web

Tags: java, aplicação-web, thread

Tenho uma aplicação web de venda de produto cantina escolar, esse processo é acessado por vários usuários simultaneamente.. tenho um método que atualiza e valida se quantidade está disponível.. preciso que esse método seja executado por um usuário de cada vez. Tentei colocar synchronized mas não obtive sucesso, segue o trecho:

```
public synchronized void atualizarQuantidadeItemCardapio(Cardapio itemCardapio) throws NegocioException {
    for (MovimentoCantina itemVenda : movimento) {
        if (itemCardapio.getProduto().getCodigo().equals(itemVenda.getProduto().getCodigo())) {
            validarProdutoEsgotado(itemCardapio);
            if (!estaVazio(itemCardapio.getQuantidade())) {
                itemCardapio = atualizarItemCardapio(itemCardapio);
                itemCardapio.setTransacao(persistencia);
                diminuirQuantidadeCardapio(itemCardapio, itemVenda);
                itemCardapio.preencherSituacao();
                itemCardapio.alterarQuantidade();
                itemCardapio.alterarVersao();
                criarLogCardapio(itemCardapio, itemVenda, CardapioLog.VENDA);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rolou alguma erro de execução/compilação ?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você quer apenas atualizar a quantidade de itens, se for isso, não tem necessidade de ser synchronized. O que você precisa é saber se está disponível, certo? Você terá que realizar a consulta antes da conclusão da compra.

Comment: Sim.. estou realizando a consulta mas como são dois usuários fazendo a mesma consulta ao mesmo.. eles pegam a mesma quantidade e realizam a compra. Exemplo: tenho um determinado produto cujo a quantidade é 1.. os dois compram ao mesmo tempo esse produto.. portanto quando realizam a consulta ambos verificam que é 1 portanto tem disponível.. ambos finalizam a venda mas era pra um deles receber o erro de produto indisponível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Syncronized funciona de 3 maneiras diferentes:

```
public synchronized void foo() { }
```

Esta versão de foo() é um método de instância, ou seja, threads diferentes podem invocar foo() simultaneamente desde que as chamadas sejam realizadas em instâncias diferentes. O lock é feito na instância em que foo() foi invocado.

```
public static synchronized void foo() { }
```

Já esta versão de foo() só pode ser executada por uma Thread por vez, pois o lock é feito no objeto Class do tipo em que foo() foi invocado.

Por último o Java ainda permite o uso de blocos synchronized:

```
public void foo() { synchronized(user) { .... } }
```

Neste caso, a política de execução vai depender do objeto passado no bloco. Se for de instância, a trava é feita na instância. Se for um atributo estático, a trava é feita no objeto Class. Ela te permite uma liberdade maior por permitir que apenas uma porção do método seja sincronizada.

Tirei essas informações literalmente de uma pergunta sobe Synchronized [link](https://www.guj.com.br/t/o-que-e-synchronized/139744/4)
Acredito que a sua solução pode tá na forma que você tá utilizando, como a descrição do problema tá muito curta não deu pra ser mais objetivo.

Comment: Tenho duas aplicações com instâncias diferentes executando esse método ao mesmo tempo, devo utilizar public static synchronized void foo() { } ? Obrigado

Comment: Se você espera criar uma espécie de gargalo, em que cada chamada espere o fim da execução da outra chamada , sim.